# Issue regarding epoch in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

I've done a web application using PHP and postgres. Now, that same application I'm translating to JavaScript and SQLite. I must say, it's not been too tough and SQLite has successfully been able to interpret the same queries as I use in postgres.

Except for this one.

```
SELECT SUM(t.subtotal)/MAX(EXTRACT(epoch FROM (r.fecha_out - r.fecha_in))/86400) AS subtotal,
COUNT(t.id) AS habitaciones FROM reserva_habitacion t 
LEFT JOIN reserva r ON t.id_reserva=r.id 
WHERE (r.fecha_in <= "2015-03-27" AND r.fecha_out > "2015-03-27") AND r.estado <> 5
```

Using the FireFox plugin "SQLiteManager" it hints me that the error is this part `epoch FROM`, but I cannot get my head around it. What am I doing wrong and how could I fix it?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

SQLite, unusually for a relational database, is completely dynamically typed, as [discussed in this manual page](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Postgres, in contrast, is strictly typed, and uses operator overloading so that `timestamp - timestamp` gives you an `interval`. An `interval` can then be passed to the SQL-standard `extract()` function, in this case to give a total number of seconds between two timestamps. (See [the manual page on Date/Time functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html).)

In SQLite, you have no such column type, so you have two choices:

- Store your DateTimes as Unix timestamps directly; at this point, the `extract epoch from` is redundant, because `r.fecha_out - r.fecha_in` will give you the difference in seconds.
- Store your DateTimes as strings in a standard format, and use [the SQLite Date and Time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to work with them. In this case, you could use `strftime('%s', foo)` to convert each value to a Unix timestamp, e.g. `strftime('%s', r.fecha_out) - strftime('%s', r.fecha_in)`